# Jquery pairing of items

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-ui-sortable

I want to implement a paring system using list and jquery.

```
 Excel Fields               DB Fields               Mapping
    email                   name                    email+emailId
    address                 emailId         >>      empId+empcode
    name                    empcode      (ADD PAIR)
    empId                   address
                                           <<
                                        (REMOVE PAIR)
```

In the above example when I select items from both(Excel Fields,DB Fields) list and click ADD PAIR it should show the pair under Mapping list and the corresponding items should be removed from respective list.
When I select a item from Mapping list and click Remove pair it should remove the item from mapping list and add the individual items to the respective list.
My question is there any jquery plugin to implement this.OR any example available on web which shows how this is done.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try this: http://www.virtuosoft.eu/code/bootstrap-duallistbox/

Comment: [a regex that your closed question](https://regex101.com/r/oW8xD1/3)

Comment: @Kerwin Thank you so much. But I am feeling very sorry for you as I have deleted the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved with simple JQuery. No need of any plugin.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#btn-add').click(function(){
    
    var selected1 = $('#select-from1 option:selected');
    var selected2 = $('#select-from2 option:selected');
    
      if(selected1.length == 0 || selected2.length == 0){
  alert("Please select options from both the select boxes");
  return;
  }
      
    $('#select-to').append("<option data-val1='"+selected1.val()+"' data-val2='"+selected2.val()+"' data-text1='"+selected1.text()+"' data-text2='"+selected2.text()+"' value='"+selected1.val()+"+"+selected2.val()+"'>"+selected1.text()+"+"+selected2.text()+"</option>");
    selected1.remove();
 selected2.remove();
    
    });
    $('#btn-remove').click(function(){
        $('#select-to option:selected').each( function() {
            $('#select-from').append("<option value='"+$(this).val()+"'>"+$(this).text()+"</option>");
   var select1_val = $(this).attr("data-val1");
   var select2_val = $(this).attr("data-val2");
   var select1_text = $(this).attr("data-text1");
   var select2_text = $(this).attr("data-text2");
   
   $('#select-from1').append("<option value='"+select1_val+"'>"+select1_text+"</option>");
   $('#select-from2').append("<option value='"+select2_val+"'>"+select2_text+"</option>");
   
            $(this).remove();
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="selectfrom" id="select-from1" size="5">
      <option value="1">Item 1</option>
      <option value="2">Item 2</option>
      <option value="3">Item 3</option>
      <option value="4">Item 4</option>
    </select>
 
 <select name="selectfrom" id="select-from2" size="5">
      <option value="1">Item 1</option>
      <option value="2">Item 2</option>
      <option value="3">Item 3</option>
      <option value="4">Item 4</option>
    </select>
 
    <a href="JavaScript:void(0);" id="btn-add">Add &raquo;</a>
    <a href="JavaScript:void(0);" id="btn-remove">&laquo; Remove</a>
 
    <select name="selectto" id="select-to" multiple size="5">
    </select>
```

Comment: Thanks. I doubt there is any plug-in for (2 select) => (1 select) combination. If you want to implement such thing at multiple pages then you can write your own custom plug-in using above JS code.